# debian lxc create error

Tags: linux, debian, lxc

I recently freshly installed Debian 8, and i want to create a linux contener based on wheezy.
But when i launch the command:

```
sudo lxc-create -n omvctr -t debian -- -r wheezy -a amd64
```

I obtain this trace :

```
Generation complete.
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `checkroot.sh' overrides LSB defaults (S).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (S) of script `checkroot.sh' overrides LSB defaults (empty).
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: umountfs Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `hwclock.sh' overrides LSB defaults (S).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 6 S) of script `hwclock.sh' overrides LSB defaults (0 6).
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for hwclockfirst.sh
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: "What is the problem?" Indeed... Does it not boot? Does it corrupt your file system? Does it cause your system to start smoking? Are there striped weasels coming out your printer in search of origami dragonfruit?

Comment: There are some errors in the output.... do you mean that these errors are not important ?

Comment: They may very well be important, but you need to be specific about the problem you are having, what you have tried on your own first to troubleshoot/repair, and a specific question you have... This is not a general "debug this for me with no input" service.

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, so I did not do anything to repair !
After installing Debian Jessie I start installing LXC, nothing else !

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you run into (sort of) a bug in [Debian LXC package](http://sources.debian.net/patches/patch/lxc/1:1.0.6-6%2Bdeb8u1/0016-lxc-debian-init.patch/), the message:

```
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for hwclockfirst.sh
```

is probably caused by this line:

```
chroot $rootfs /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f hwclockfirst.sh disable
```

which is trying to disable autostart of several services inside new container, but `hwclockfirst.sh` service doesn't exist. It would be cleaner if the script would check if service exists and then tried to disable it.

**TL;DR**: no need to worry :)